# Chrome white pages and image not loading

Tags: chrome-for-android, 4.4-kitkat

Since I upgraded to Android 4.4 (Kitkat), I'm having a lot of problems with anything web related.

Often, when calling an URL, the loading is fast and shows nothing: the page remains white. Even refreshing won't do. Clearing the cash doesn't help either. I have to close all tabs, serveral times, relaunch Chrome or even reboot my device to get the page to load. Even then, I'm not entirely sure if rebooting the device did make it work or it's just random.

Sometimes, when loading an animated gif, it will start to load and stop and never play again. It could also just stay on the first frame.

Also, the webview of reddit's app does the same thing, I switched it to show the link inside the browser instead to see if it helps, but it doesn't.

I'm don't know if the Play Store has webviews in it, but sometimes the app just doesn't load anything and the page is also white.

At first I thought it may be my connection, but I tested over nealry 10 wifi (home, work, cafe, friends, etc.) and it seems to be very random as it starts to act weird from over time.

My device is a Nexus 4.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser, like Boat Browser or Dolphin Browser? Is the behavior still the same?

Comment: Testing with Boat Browser and so far it's working well. I like Chrome thought :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already tested, trying out different browsers might be a good alternative. I suggest you try either [Boat Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boatbrowser.free) or [Dolphin Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.mgeek.TunnyBrowser).

My stand for [Chrome Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) still remains. It is still an immature browser, and lacks many features / add-ons that are available in other browsers.

Comment: At first, I must say I didn't want to believe it. I made a _lot_ of testing this week-end, loading images in both browser, testing different setup, etc. Boat Browser was ALWAYS loading the image where Chrome failed so many times. I don't even know how to report this to the Chromium team.